# C#/MonoDevelop: GTK MessageDialogs require a doubleclick to close - why?

Tags: c#, mono, gtk

I'm a newbie programmer writting a program in MonoDevelop in C# and have a porblem with my gtk MessageDialogs.

The close button on the window boarders of my GTK Message dialogues require a double click to actually close them. The close button on the dialogue its self works fine. Could someone please tell me how I can fix this below is the code:

```
  if (fchDestination.CurrentFolder == fchTarget.CurrentFolder) {
   MessageDialog msdSame = new MessageDialog(this, DialogFlags.Modal, MessageType.Error, ButtonsType.Close, "Destination directory cannot be the same as the target directory");
   msdSame.Title="Error";
   if ((ResponseType) msdSame.Run() == ResponseType.Close) {
    msdSame.Destroy();
   }
   return;
  }

  if (fchTarget.CurrentFolder.StartsWith(fchDestination.CurrentFolder)) {
   MessageDialog msdContains = new MessageDialog(this, DialogFlags.Modal, MessageType.Error, ButtonsType.Close, "error");
   msdContains.Title="Error";
   if ((ResponseType) msdContains.Run() == ResponseType.Close) {
    msdContains.Destroy();
   }
   return;
  }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The response value given when you click on a dialog's "close window" button is not `CLOSE`, but `DELETE_EVENT`. That's why the `destroy` method is never called and the dialog lingers. The second time you close it (out of the context of the `run` method), the dialog is destroyed normally.

In short, you also need to check for `ResponseType.DeleteEvent`.

**Update:**

In code:

```
MessageDialog msdSame = ...
...
ResponseType response = (ResponseType) msdSame.Run();
if (response == ResponseType.Close || response == ResponseType.DeleteEvent) {
  msdSame.Destroy();
}
```

Or, as ptomato mentions, you don't need to check the response, considering the user only has one choice: "close".

```
MessageDialog msdSame = ...
...
msdSame.Run();
msdSame.Destroy();
```

Comment: Agree with the explanation, but you don't need to check for any `ResponseType` since the user's only choice is "Close". Just call `Run()` and then `Destroy()`.

Comment: I tried the following code but still get the error :s where abouts am i going wrong? thanks for your help :)   

MessageDialog msdSame = new MessageDialog(this, DialogFlags.Modal, MessageType.Error, ButtonsType.Close, "You cannot sync two folders that are the same");
   msdSame.Title="Error";
   //if user clicks close then close message box
   if ((ResponseType) msdSame.Run() == ResponseType.Close || (ResponseType) msdSame.Run() == ResponseType.DeleteEvent) {
    msdSame.Destroy();
   }

Comment: hi ptomato sorry didnt see your comment! I'm kinda new to programming :s whereabouts do I need to call the run() and destroy in my code? thanks

Comment: I've updated the answer to explain it in code. You were almost correct, but you need to only call `Run` once and store the return value. The code that you had was actually causing the dialog to be run twice.

Comment: Hi thanks for all your help I greatly appreciate it :D I got it to work in the end using ptomato's method, Johannes when I tired your code I got the following error on this line

ResponseType response = msdContains.Run();

Error CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type `int' to `Gtk.ResponseType'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

I was just wonndering what I can do to correct this as latter on in my program I may want a message box with multiple options so would like to understand how this works :)
thanks

Comment: Ah, my mistake. Apparently Run returns an int, which in this case we need to cast to ResponseType: `(ResponseType) dlgSame.Run()`. I've updated the answer again.

Comment: Yup that sorted it :D
Thanks Johannes really appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 0):

May be both the conditions get satisfied and hence you get two msgbox and it appears you've to give a double click to close it

Comment: hmmm but when I click on the close button on the msgbox its self the window closes straight away, its only the close button on the msgboxes window decoration that is a problem :S that why im so confused

Answer (score 0):

A sample class could be:

```
using System;
using Gtk; 
namespace Visitors.Clases.MessageBox
{   
    public static class MessageBox 
    {
        public static Gtk.ResponseType Show(Gtk.Window window, Gtk.DialogFlags dialogflags, MessageType msgType,ButtonsType btnType,string Message,String caption)
        {

            MessageDialog md = new MessageDialog (window,dialogflags,msgType,btnType, Message);
            md.Title = caption;
            ResponseType tp = (Gtk.ResponseType)md.Run();       
            md.Destroy(); 
            return tp;
        }
    }
}
```

The class in use:

```
ResponseType result = MessageBox.Show(this,DialogFlags.Modal,MessageType.Error,ButtonsType.Ok,Error,"ERROR");
if (result == Gtk.ResponseType.Yes)
{
    MessageBox.Show (this, DialogFlags.Modal, MessageType.Other,ButtonsType.Ok, "YES", "EJEMPLO");
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show (this, DialogFlags.Modal, MessageType.Other,ButtonsType.Ok, "NO", "EJEMPLO");
}
```